# I still get confused with "prefer to have O + (to) V" grammar

Tags: grammar

What kind of grammar (the name of grammar) am I getting confused in the following sentences? And which one is the correct one?

- I prefer to have my wife does the homework by herself.
- I prefer to have my wife do the homework by herself.
- I prefer to have my wife to do the homework by herself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second one is correct.

The type of clause you get after *prefer to have...* is a **non-finite clause**. This type of clause is dependent and its verb is *non-finite*, which is typically an infinitive, participle or gerund. In this case it's an infinitive.

If you do want a finite verb in your subclause, you could construct your sentence like this:

> I prefer *it that* my wife does the homework by herself.

About the difference between *prefer to have X **to do** something* (incorrect) and *prefer to have X **do** something* (correct), that all depends on the verb in the main clause. The *to have* is always followed by a **bare infinitive**. This is different per verb, the verb *to get X **to do** something* is followed by a **to-infinitive**.

Comment: +1 I have updated my question. The previous one had a typo.

Comment: I updated my answer and added a solution to the *to do* vs *do* problem.

Comment: +1 to this answer, but also: In the alternative construction given in the answer, the word "to" is optional. Thus, the sentence could also be "I prefer *that* my wife does the homework by herself." In both cases, the object of the verb "prefer" is the noun clause "that my wife does the homework by herself", but in one case it is given as a pronoun ("it") whose antecedent is then given immediately after ("that my wife…"), while in the other case the noun clause ("that my wife…") is directly in the object position.

Answer (score -1):

By saying "I prefer to" it becomes present-tense or future-tense.
Therefore

"does" would be past-tense

"do" would be present and/or future

"to-do" would be future-tense but in this case, your sentence contains "I prefer to have *my*"

For example.

> **I prefer to have to do the homework.**
>
> I prefer to have my wife to do the homework.
>
> **I prefer to have my wife do the homework.**

The reason **to have to** is appropriate but not after **my** is because , like Sander said, you cannot normally have a noun before *to*

Having the sentence cut out can be used correctly.

> **I will ask my wife to do the homework by herself.**
>
> **I'm beginning *to* wonder if my wife needs *to do* the homework by herself**

Comment: "does" is not past tense ever.

Comment: I have no enough reputation to down vote.